# Why does the restored file hasn't previous symbols?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, decode, recovery, file-recovery

I restored the text file (file.txt) after accidentally deleting it with [MiniTool Power 
 Data Recovery 8.0](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/)

Although the recovered file weighs the same (584 KB), but it looks completely different. It looks like this:
[image: print screen of recovered filed]
I understand that my file was broken after recovering. But why doesn't the file contains any previous symbols (Latin and Cyrillic characters)?

Answer (score 2):

The software could not fulfill your expectations. Your file was not recovered, but an unrelated piece/sector of the mass storage medium. It contains random binary junk.

Comment: Just commenting here to weight in: that is indeed what took place.